# Oracle - Compile view too slow

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle10g

I have a view in oracle that can't compile. The view is really simple, with 6 tables (5 inner joins) and less then 10000 rows in query result.

The view's query is like the example below.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW owner.X 
as
SELECT vpc.field_1, vpc.field_2
FROM casp.table_0 bpc
INNER JOIN owner.table_1 b
  ON b.id_bpc = bpc.id_bpc
INNER JOIN owner.table_2 a
  ON a.id_b = b.id_b
INNER JOIN owner.table_3 cb
  ON cb.id_a = a.id_cb
INNER JOIN owner.table_4 cbw
  ON cbw.id_cb = cb.id_cb
inner join owner.view_1 vpc
  ON bpc.id_bpc = vpc.id_bpc
WHERE vpc.cod = 1
```

When I try to compile, the view start to processing, but the compilation never ends.

If I take the query off and replace a table that exists from other that don't exists on my database, the server spend about 15sec just to return the error ORA-00942 (table or view does not exists). In a different database (development) is least the 1sec.

I don't know what happend to the server to start this strange bug.

The Oracle version is 10G.

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a database where users are trying to query the view?  If so, you're probably being blocked by those users (a query needs a lock that prevents DDL before it can run).  You'd need to retry or stop the other sessions before changing the view.

Comment: No, the view hasn't being blocked by users. I try to create a view with other name, but didn't happend again. Then I replaced the "inner joins" to old join syntax in a new view and worked. It's really strange, because I have a lot of other code with regular join that has no problems.

Comment: Then what was your session waiting on?  What wait events was Oracle reporting?

Comment: @FelipeReis There might be a a problem with the data dictionary causing recursive queries to run slowly.  Behind many SQL statements, especially for DDL, Oracle runs other SQL statements to update the data dictionary.  Look for queries running at the same time as the `CREATE VIEW`, with a query like this: `select elapsed_time/1000000 seconds, sql_text, executions, parsing_schema_name from gv$sql where users_executing > 0;`.  There might be a slow recursive query because of missing data dictionary or fixed object stats.  If yo ufind something, edit the question and we'll take a look.

Comment: I agree with @JonHeller that it's worth checking data dictionary statistics. In development environments with lots of developers dropping and rebuilding their schemas the performance of data dictionary tasks can really deteriorate if the stats are too stale.

Answer (score 0):

I had simmilar problem with view performance - select from view took more than 30 sec whereas the underlying query took less than 1 sec. I was searching for a way to tune up my views and found two: either do not use views, or use materialized views. Later I found [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/art_hints_views.htm) describing the reason very clearly.

Comment: This question is about the length of time it took to **compile** the view, not how long selecting from it took to return results. Also, a flat rule of never using views is silly,and materialized views are a particular solution to a specific set of problems.